# Facebook - Exchange code for access_token (C# / Windows Phone / NO SDK)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am authenticating to facebook via oauth 2.0 using C# on a Windows Phone.  I am only using REST service calls.  Not using the Facebook SDK at all.  I am currently able to launch a browser on the phone, have the user sign in and approve the scope of the app, and retrieve my authorization code.

However, I cannot for the life of me exchange my authorization code for an access token.

My Facebook app has the following switches turned on under 'Settings' --> 'Advanced':

- Native or Desktop App?  [Yes]
- Is your App Secret embedded? [No]
- Client OAuth Login?  [Yes]
- Embedded Browser OAuth Login?  [Yes]

I should note that my model authenticates the user and retrieves the authorization code all on the phone, and then I pass the authorization code up to a secure service where I exchange it for an access_token.  I was having issues though, so I have temporarily moved this server call into my phone app for troubleshooting, but I get the same error.

The error I receive is:

{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

I have tried several combinations of things including wrapping the authorization code with HTTPUtility.UrlEncode()

Here is a sample of my code (actual values swapped out).

```
        string FacebookClientID = "123456789123456789";
        string FacebookRedirectURI = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        string FacebookClientSecret = "d156df15dfds1f561fds5f1ds6f1";
        string FacebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

        HttpRequestMessage tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(FacebookUrl + "?client_id=" + FacebookClientID + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FacebookRedirectURI) + "&client_secret=" + FacebookClientSecret + "&code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FacebookAuthorizationCode)));

        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await hc.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

        var json = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

json ends up containing the error string reported above stating that my authorization code is bad.

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,

goodbar

Comment: Dah... nevermind, I was setting the authorization code .ToLower().  Removed that and now works like a charm...

Comment: For the record though, I am able to get the access_token with ALL of the switches in the Facebook settings --> advanced turned off

Comment: You should post this as an answer if solved, and accept it

Comment: will do, the site made me wait 8 hours before I could answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dah... nevermind, I was setting the authorization code .ToLower() prior to exchanging it for an access_token. Removed that and now works like a charm...

For the record though, I am able to get the access_token with ALL of the switches in the Facebook settings --> advanced turned off